# Electron app.makeSingleInstance is allowing unlimited instances

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

My **Main.js** code is:

```
let mainWindow = null;

const shouldQuit = app.makeSingleInstance((commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
  // Someone tried to run a second instance, we should focus our window.
  if (mainWindow) {
    if (mainWindow.isMinimized()){
      mainWindow.restore();
    }
    mainWindow.show();
    mainWindow.focus();
  } 
});

if (shouldQuit) {
  app.quit();
}
```

This is basically identical to the Electron docs, and to all examples I can find on the web. Has anyone else had this issue? I see on the web a good deal of people saying this code doesn't work for them.

I am building my app using `Electron-Builder`.

Thank you.

Comment: Works as expected for me on Ubuntu 16.10. What OS are you running?

Comment: Thanks Justin. Windows 7 Professional x64. I have found other people with similar issues, but no solutions unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This started working some time ago, and I have since upgraded Electron a few times, so I am forced to assume this was an Electron bug in versions below 1.4.

Countless other experiences on the web that also went unsolved during this time lend credence to this idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
// Force Single Instance Application
const shouldQuit = app.makeSingleInstance((commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
    // Someone tried to run a second instance, we should focus our window.
    if (win) {
        if (win.isMinimized()) win.restore()
        win.focus()
    }
})

if (shouldQuit) {
    app.quit()
    return
}

...
```

Refs: [app.makeSingleInstance(callback):](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#user-content-appmakesingleinstancecallback) and [dominikfiala's comment](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4478#issuecomment-287314235)